# Insert data to table from two data table

Tags: c#, sql

I need to insert data from two data table to table

my table 
has three columns

> (ID , wordId,docId,value)

my code

```
DataTable document = new DataTable();
dt = WTA.GetData();
document = AFS.GetTheDocument();

foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < document.Rows.Count; i++)
   {                            
      double TFij = VSM.getTF(document.Rows[i]["document"].ToString(), 
                              dr["word"].ToString());
      DITA.Insert(Convert.ToInt32(document.Rows[i]["id"]),
                  Convert.ToInt32(dr["id"]), TFij);
   }
}
```

I get an error

```
 :conflict FK ;
```

I know some problem with my loops .....

Comment: What's the structure of the original tables?

Comment: int , int ,int , double no problem

Comment: but you are inserting int,int,double ?

Comment: You insert three columns where originally it's four.Third column is int and u try to add double in your line code "      DITA.Insert(Convert.ToInt32(document.Rows[i]["id"]),
                  Convert.ToInt32(dr["id"]), TFij);"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting a conflict with a foreign key then you are likely running into an issue with the database layout.

Perhaps you have a table where the wordid or the docid has to be registered first.  Have a look at your database structure as you might need to insert the doc and word id's first and then add them to this table.